# How to combine 2 poly-line sets (2 road network) from 2 shape files to form a joint road network?

Tags: netlogo

[image: Screenshot of the road network]

I have 2 sets of polylines that are loaded into NetLogo from 2 shapefiles. The two sets of polylines (blue and cyan) represent two sets of road networks. I want my agents to be able to travel from one road network to the other where ever they are intersected. I already know how to create nodes and links for each gis file separately, but I am unaware of how to combine them (join at intersections) to form a joint road network. Any ideas on how to do this?

The code below creates links and nodes for the road networks separately.

```
extensions [gis]
breed [nodes node]
set guo-roads gis:load-dataset "roads.shp"
set guo-routier gis:load-dataset "routier.shp"

to setup
create-road-network-guo-roads
create-road-network-guo-routier
end

to create-road-network-guo-roads
foreach gis:feature-list-of guo-roads[
i ->
  foreach gis:vertex-lists-of i[
  j ->
  let first-node-point nobody
  let previous-node-point nobody
    foreach j [
    k ->
    let location gis:location-of k
    if not empty? location [
    ifelse any? nodes with [xcor = item 0 location and ycor = item 1 location]
    []
    [
    create-nodes 1[
    set xcor item 0 location
    set ycor item 1 location
    set size 0.23
    set shape "circle"
    set color 23
    set hidden? false
    ]
  ]
;to create links
  let node-here (nodes with [xcor = item 0 and ycor = item 1 location])
  ifelse previous-node-point = nobody
  [set first-node-point node-here]
  [let who-node 0
   let who prev 0
   ask node-here
   [create-link-with previous-node-point
   set who-node who]
   [ask previous-node-point[
   set who-prev who
   ]
 ]
  set previous-node-point one-of node-here
 ]
]
]
]  
end

to create-road-network-guo-routier
; repeat the same steps as create-road-netowrk-guo-roads
end
```