# Error with netlogo gis extension vertex-lists-of

Tags: gis, netlogo, vertex

I want to extract points from line feature from shapefile.

I have search for solutions, it shows that most of people use gis:vertex-lists-of to do this.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352238/how-to-combine-2-poly-line-sets-2-road-network-from-2-shape-files-to-form-a-jo),

However I got an error message below when I try to do that:

Extension exception: not a VectorFeature:

org.myworldgis.netlogo.VectorDataset@ca24265

error while observer running GIS:VERTEX-LISTS-OF

called by procedure DRAW-CITIES

called by Button 'draw-cities'

Code below:

```
to draw-cities
  gis:set-drawing-color red
  gis:draw cities-dataset 1
  foreach gis:vertex-lists-of cities-dataset [
    a ->
  ]
end
```

cities-dataset is a points collection shapefile from Netlogo library ""GIS general examples" model

I don't understand that even I put a points feature in the function, I just got an error.

Do I misuse the function? How can I corectly use it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is because your foreach function is missing the action steps a foreach function looks something like this:

```
foreach [1 2 3][a -> print a + 1]
```

If you wanted to do something like the code you linked to then it would look like this:

```
extensions [ gis ]

globals [ cities-dataset]

breed [ cities city ]
breed [nodes node]

cities-own [ name country population ]

to setup
  set cities-dataset gis:load-dataset "C:/Program Files/NetLogo 6.2.2/app/models/Code Examples/Extensions Examples/gis/data/cities.shp"
  draw-cities
end

to draw-cities
  gis:set-drawing-color red
  gis:draw cities-dataset 1
  foreach gis:feature-list-of cities-dataset[
    i ->
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of i[
      j ->
      let first-node-point nobody
      let previous-node-point nobody
      foreach j [
        k ->
        let location gis:location-of k
        if not empty? location [
          ifelse any? nodes with [
           xcor = item 0 location and ycor = item 1 location
          ]
          []
          [
            create-nodes 1[
              set xcor item 0 location
              set ycor item 1 location
              set size 0.23
              set shape "circle"
              set color 23
              set hidden? false
            ]
          ]
          ;to create links
          let node-here (nodes with [
            xcor = item 0 location and ycor = item 1 location
          ])
          ifelse previous-node-point = nobody
          [set first-node-point node-here]
          [let who-node 0
            let who-prev 0
            ask node-here
            [create-link-with previous-node-point
              set who-node who]
            ask previous-node-point[
              set who-prev who
              ]
            set previous-node-point one-of node-here
          ]
        ]
      ] 
    ]
  ]
end
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking to do, but feel free to ask for more help.